# Why does this random, unexpected horizontal line appear in IE7?

Tags: javascript, css, templates, yui, stylesheet

I am using YUI's datatable (http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/datatable/) to make a table.  But notice something very wrong...sometimes, there is a line that appears on top of a result, **only in IE7**.

This may or may not be related to the YUI plugin. Does anyone know how to fix this? Thanks.!

Edit: For some reason, it only appears at that pixel. (not necessarily at that result...but at that height from the top)

Comment: I'd suggest that in your next question you include either (or preferably **both**) code for your web-page or a link to a live demo of that code. What you have here seems to be a guessing game of what *might* be wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check THe html code is there any difference for that row ? any at all.

Comment: Well anything to compare would be nice try using firefox-s firebug to inspect it.

Comment: Could it be the DataTable status message box? Is it a single row of pixels, or a white box with a black line below it?